# About function "include" in PHP

Tags: php

I have a php file for example file2.php in the subdirectory of script_client, in the head of file I include "../../include/connection.php". On my localhost it works fine. But when I put it on the server, it always shows "failed to open stream: No such file or directory", I don't understand why. Can anyone help me?

- Directory1

  - include

    - connection.php
    - file1.php
  - script

    - script_client

      - file2.php

Comment: Try using an absolute path `include '/include/connection.php';`.

Comment: Are permissions set correctly?

Comment: maybe a stupid question, but have you uploaded them all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your permitions or, instead, do it from server root

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/include/connection.php'
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps your include path is not set to the directory you expect it to be. Try using get_include_path(). If that is the case, you can set the path by calling set_include_path.

See php.net documentation for further information.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php